# Forecast using R dataframes, zoo and real dates on results

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

I have a CSV with values like

```
ref_date;wings;airfoil;turbines
2015-03-31;123,22;22,77;99,0
2015-04-30;123,22;28,77;99,0
2015-05-31;123,22;22,177;02,0
2015-06-30;56,288;22,77;99,0
```

That I read into a data frame, and convert it to a time series, with

```
df_agg = aggregate(df$wings, by=list(date=df$ref_date), FUN=mean)
df_agg['date'] = as.Date(df_agg[['date']], format='%Y-%m-%d')
tt = xts(df_agg[,c('x')], order.by=df_agg$date)
```

So now I have `tt`, a `xts` object. To use the `forecast` package, I have to convert it to a `ts` object, so I use `zoo`:

```
pred = forecast(zoo(tt))

df_pred = as.data.frame(pred)
```

But, to be able to get a result with a column with dates instead of a sequence of numbers, I have to convert it back with

```
zoo(df_pred, as.Date(as.numeric(rownames(df_pred))))
```

and now I have a result like

```
             Forecast  Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2015-07-30   12          10      15      11       14
2015-08-31   13.4        11      15.4    11.2     13
```

Is there a way to accomplish the same without having to go back and forth between data frame, xts, zoo, ts and zoo again?

In Python, this would be something like

```
 from statsmodels.api import sm
 df = pd.read_csv(file_csv)
 df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
 y_pred = sm.ARIMA(df)
```

Comment: Why Python pandas tagged here? R has a built-in [ARIMA method](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html).

Comment: Python as tagged because a lot of data scientists that work with Python work with R and the Python example can help the understanding of what I´m trying to achieve with the question.

Answer (score 4):

**1) zoo** The development version of the forecast package has `as.ts.forecast` and the development version of zoo (to become zoo version 1.8.0) has an enhanced `as.zoo.ts` which by default applies yearmon/yearqtr for ts series with frequencies of 4 and 12.  Together these would allow the code of the question to be written much more compactly.  Because the forecast package has no explicit support for non-ts time series define a simple one-line zoo method for forecast.  Then read in the data using `read.zoo`. To keep this self-contained using the data in the Note at the end we use `text=Lines` but in reality it would be replaced with something like `myfile.dat`. The `read.zoo` command also applies yearmon class to the index and aggregates it using mean.  Finally run `forecast` and then convert the output to zoo class.  This entire sequence only involves one conversion and the only reason that was needed is that forecast only supports ts.

```
library(forecast)
library(zoo)

as.zoo.forecast <- function(x, ...) as.zoo(as.ts(x))

z <- read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",", 
  FUN = as.yearmon, aggregate = mean)
f <- forecast(z$wings)
as.zoo(f)
```

Until those new package versions are released you can run the code below before the above.  After the new forecast and zoo packages are released the code above alone will be sufficient.

```
# taken from development verison of forecast package
as.ts.forecast <- function(x, ...){
   df <- ts(as.matrix(forecast:::as.data.frame.forecast(x)))
   tsp(df) <- tsp(x$mean)
   return(df)
}

# can use this until devel version of zoo released
as.zoo.ts <- function(x, ...) {
  z <- zoo:::as.zoo.ts(x)
  if (frequency(z) == 4) time(z) <- as.yearqtr(time(z))
  if (frequency(z) == 12) time(z) <- as.yearmon(time(z))
  z
}
```

**2) ts** Another possibility is to use `"ts"` class only making use of zoo to read the data in.  Using the above `z` and `as.ts.forecast` (which, as mentioned, can be omitted once the devel version of the forecast pkg becomes current):

```
tt <- as.ts(z)
f <- forecast(tt[, "wings"])
as.ts(f)
```

**Note:**  Above we used this input:

```
Lines <- "ref_date;wings;airfoil;turbines
2015-03-31;123,22;22,77;99,0
2015-04-30;123,22;28,77;99,0
2015-05-31;123,22;22,177;02,0
2015-06-30;56,288;22,77;99,0"
```

Comment: Is there a way to set an index to any of the objects, in the `pandas` sense, so it can be conserved throughout the computations?

Comment: Not directly if you use `forecast`.    You can always write a wrapper function to hide the conversions.

Comment: Is there a better option to do ARIMA with auto selection besides `forecast`?

Comment: I would stick with the `forecast` package.